# (PHP) Get total hours year and months of calendar items

Tags: php, calendar

Dear better coders than me,

I'm building a 'little' script which gives me the following information:

- Total hours in a selected year of all calendar items (this works in code below)
- Total hours in all months (Jan to Dec) of all the calendar items (from the selected year).
- total hours of Dec in the year *before* the selected year (of calendar items).
- total hours of Jan in the year *after* the selected year (of calendar items).

Im breaking my head around this, because i can probably write this in a very inefficient way with lots of if's and else. But i like to learn. Who wants to help? what i have so far (this code works and gives me the total hours of the selected year):

```
$totalhours = 0;

//selected year var
$sel_year = 2017;

$prev_year = $sel_year -1;
$cur_year = date('Y', time());
$next_year = $sel_year +1;

// loop through all calendar data (.ics data)
foreach ($events as $event) {


    // Start and end unixtimestamp of calendar item.
    $dtstart = $ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event['DTSTART']);
    $dtend = $ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event['DTEND']);

    //which year the calendar items starts and end
    $startevent_year = date('Y', $dtstart);
    $endevent_year = date('Y', $dtstart);


    //Calculates total hours of calendar item in this loop
    $seconds = $dtend - $dtstart;
    $hours = $seconds/3600;


    //Add to total if item is in selected year
    if(($startevent_year == $sel_year) && ($endevent_year == $sel_year)){

        $totalhours += $hours;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for that:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2017-01-01 10:00:00');
$d2 = new DateTime('2017-01-02 12:00:00');

$diff = $d2->diff($d1);
$hours = $diff->days * 24 + $diff->h;

echo $hours;  // 26
```

**ALSO:** http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: That's a handy function, thanks. But it doesn't give me the calendar hours of all the months.

Comment: @Edwin I'm not sure what you mean, but you can pass almost everything to `DateTime` constructor: things like `"first day of December"` and `"last day of last year"` will help you to define valid date ranges.